# Filter data frame with a boolean vector based on one column

Tags: pandas

I'm somewhat new to pandas. 
I have a data frame, `words_df` with two columns. The **first column** (`[[0]]`) is a list of words, the second are values that I want to use in processes further downstream. 
Looks something like this:

```
                   a:State-word  occurrences
0                      FIRE         1535
1                       BRR         1189
2                     GREEN          521
3                    ORANGE          504
4                    PURPLE          503
5                      BLUE          482
6                    VIOLET          480
7                    YELLOW          445
8                    INDIGO          434
9                     BLACK          392
10                    WHITE          381
11                     PINK          322
...
```

I have a second list of words that I want to filter against. 
If a word is in my `filter_list`, remove the row in my `words_df`.

So far I've managed:
`filter_list = words_df[[0]].isin(filter_list)`

which I then attempt to do this with:
`words_df[~filter_list]`

It sort of works, but mostly doesn't.
looks like this on the other end:

```
               a:State-word  occurrences
0                       NaN          NaN
1                       NaN          NaN
2                       NaN          NaN
3                       NaN          NaN
4                    PURPLE          NaN
5                       NaN          NaN
6                       NaN          NaN
7                    YELLOW          NaN
8                    INDIGO          NaN
9                       NaN          NaN
10                      NaN          NaN
11                      NaN          NaN
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
               a:State-word  occurrences
1                    PURPLE          503
2                    YELLOW          445
3                    INDIGO          434
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close to the answer

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({'a:State-word': ['FIRE','BRR', 'GREEN', 'ORANGE', 'PURPLE', 'BLUE', 'VIOLET'],
                'occurrences': [1535, 1189, 521, 504, 503, 482, 480]})
filter_list = ['FIRE', 'BRR', 'GREEN', 'ORANGE', 'BLUE']
df

#   a:State-word  occurrences
# 0         FIRE         1535
# 1          BRR         1189
# 2        GREEN          521
# 3       ORANGE          504
# 4       PURPLE          503
# 5         BLUE          482
# 6       VIOLET          480

df[~df['a:State-word'].isin(filter_list)]

#   a:State-word  occurrences
# 4       PURPLE          503
# 6       VIOLET          480
```

Comment: so the problem was `words_df[[0]]` I had to use the colname? I wouldn't have tried that except the colname had looked too weird to mess with! Any idea why using the column reference by index doesn't work?

Comment: I think `words_df[[0]]` returns a `DataFrame` and not a `Series`. If you want to use index, my advice is to explicitly use `iloc` like this `df[~df.iloc[:,0].isin(filter_list)]`